# QT installation on ubuntu

Tags: qt

I am trying to install QT on ubuntu.I need to install Active perl by using this URL:

http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads

I have downloaded all files but not getting way to install this on ubuntu.Please guide me.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why dont you just

```
apt-get install qt
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install qt`